# vue awesome swiper install failed on windows

Tags: windows, vue.js, npm

I'm trying to install `vue-awesome-swiper` with npm using this command

```
npm i vue-awesome-swiper --save
```

I'm getting this error

```
npm ERR! Line breaks can't be quoted on Windows

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-06T18_35_21_789Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I opened the log and I figured that the problem is caused by this line here

```
80 info run swiper@5.4.5 postinstall node_modules/swiper echo "[35m[1mLove Swiper? Support Vladimir's work by donating or pledging on patreon:[22m[39m
80 info run  > [32mhttps://patreon.com/vladimirkharlampidi[0m
80 info run "
```

As you can see from the log here it's triggering postinstall script and it's just trying to print a message to support the package author.

To fix this issue you can simply install the package without running any scripts with the `--ignore-scripts` flag like this:

```
npm i vue-awesome-swiper --save --ignore-scripts
```